# JPA framework for both SQL and NoSQL databases

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, hibernate-ogm

We are currently designing a new Spring Boot microservice and we are searching for technology, which can allow us to implement a single interface to use both SQL and NoSQL databases. For now, we use document-oriented database in our prototype, but some of our clients want to store data in RDBMS.
We want to be able to set the database type in configuration for compiled application. Is there any JPA framework or another platform, which could help us not to implement different database types on code level?

We considered Hibernate ORM and OGM but understood what they solve separate problems for SQL and NoSQL databases. Maybe we can use some of the Spring data modules?

Comment: Not sure about Hibernate options, but EclipseLink as a JPA provider has noSQL support: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/NoSQL